# Random Text with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output a random word into a specific html element. I'm almost there - but I think I'm messing up the part which prints the text...

Can anyone give me a tip as to where I'm going wrong ?

```
var txtGreeting = 10;
var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (txtGreeting - 1)) + 1;
var greeting = new Array();
greeting[1] = "hello",
greeting[2] = "ciao",
greeting[3] = "welcome",
greeting[4] = "howdy",
greeting[5] = "greetings",
greeting[6] = "salut",
greeting[7] = "hallo",
greeting[8] = "hola",
greeting[9] = "Gday",
greeting[10] = "Hey",

document.getElementById("title").html = "greeting[randomCount]";
```

Comment: Try `.innerHTML` ;) So close! There's also some minor issues with your syntax for instance those `,`s should be `;`s.

Comment: adding to what @NiettheDarkAbsol said, you also don't need the `"greeting[randomCount]"` bit wrapped in quotes, since that will be interpreted as a literal string of text.

Comment: you know that you can separate variable declarations by commas, right?  The way he has it isn't exactly correct...but barring that, it's pretty acceptable.

like: 
var a =1,
    b =2,
    c =3,
    d = 4;

Comment: Stop using `new Array`!!! And the way you are using it is wrong: 1. It should be `new Array()` 2: An array starts at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm just going to tidy up your code for you. What you've written was a great attempt!

```
var greetings = [
      "hello"
    , "ciao"
    , "welcome"
    , "howdy"
    , "greetings"
    , "salut"
    , "hallo"
    , "hola"
    , "Gday"
    , "Hey"
];
var greeting_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * greetings.length);
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = greetings[greeting_id];
```

This uses an array literal, a "proper" zero-based array (makes picking a random index easier), dynamic `.length` property so you don't have to rewrite code just because you want to add a new greeting, and finally `.innerHTML` instead of just `.html`.

Comment: I understand why people use "comma-left" with array literals, but I find it so darn ugly! :)

Comment: @Xotic750 Haha! Me too, but that's how it's done at work, so sometimes I just reflexively do it... I've become one of them! Save me!

Answer (score -1):

just put "greeting[randomCount]" out of quotes and it should be fine.

Comment: Incorrect. .html is not a native Javascript function, so it will not work. (it is JQuery based)